# Import variables into aurelia-dialog view-model or view

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

Is there a way to import additional variables/data from the dialog-service to the controller?

For example I have an array of possible options in a form of my app-view. I fetch the data via an API from a server.

I'd like to edit an entry with an aurelia-dialog and don't want to fetch the data again to avoid unnecessary traffic in my app.

How can i pass the array additionally to the model. Pack it all together in an Object and unwrap it in the controller?
As far as I know the activate-method of the controller only takes one argument, doesn't it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the example in the repository exactly what you are looking for?
The `person` attribute is passed to the dialog service via the `settings` object (`model: this.person`). This may be data you fetched from the server. As you mentioned, you can of course add multiple objects to the model as well which will be available in the `activate()` method of your dialogs vm.

```
import {EditPerson} from './edit-person';
import {DialogService} from 'aurelia-dialog';
export class Welcome {
  static inject = [DialogService];
  constructor(dialogService) {
    this.dialogService = dialogService;
  }
  person = { firstName: 'Wade', middleName: 'Owen', lastName: 'Watts' };
  submit(){
    this.dialogService.open({ viewModel: EditPerson, model: this.person}).then(response => {
      if (!response.wasCancelled) {
        console.log('good - ', response.output);
      } else {
        console.log('bad');
      }
      console.log(response.output);
    });
  }
}
```